# In HMS, How to change app signatures for new version of application which already released?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I  have released 4.4.2 -v ,4.5.0-v and 4.5.1-v apk versions

I want to change the app signature  ,while submitting new version I am  getting error like - The keystore used by your App is inconsistent with the version on the shelf please refer the rule 8.6 of "App Gallery Review Guidelines"

How to submit the apk with different app signature?
I would like to remove 4.5.0 too.

Answer (score 0):

Once a signature key is generated in AppGallery Connect or uploaded by you, it cannot be modified.

For details,check the following documents:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-introduction-0000001051379577

Comment: Instead of updating new version can cp delete the all previous versions and upload fresh apk with different signature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For this You need to remove the application from App Gallery Connect, then after only it is possible to delete the application.
After the application is submitted successfully for removing, the app status changes to Pending removal. Huawei operations personnel will handle your application in 1 to 2 working days.

Note: Removing an app will not release the package name used by the app. A package name can be released only after you delete the app.

For details, check the following documents:

Remove the app: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-remove_app

Delete the app: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-delete_app

Note: For released app, changing signature is not recommended.